# Querying the last entry in a column based on several criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

This is actually my first time to ask a question, but please bear with me as I've been having a hard time looking for an answer amidst all the questions here.

It's actually quite simple, but I just can't figure it out.

```
SELECT DateOfPurchase, 
TypeOfFruit,
Quantity
FROM FruitInventory
WHERE TypeOfFruit = 'apple' OR
TypeOfFruit = 'orange' OR 
TypeOfFruit = 'banana'
```

I just want to see, which item was purchased last out of all the three types of fruit, I tried using

```
MAX(DISTINCT DateOfPurchase)
```

but it does not seem to work...

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is your RDBMs? It may be different from each other.

Comment: My thought as well.  Are you working with SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc?

Comment: sql server 2012 sir, t-sql

Comment: Saying "which item was purchased last out of all the three types of fruit"  is not clear. Can you provide a sample expected result (and possibly test data) please.

Comment: Does `SELECT MAX(DateOfPurchase) 
FROM FruitInventory
WHERE TypeOfFruit = 'apple' OR
TypeOfFruit = 'orange' OR 
TypeOfFruit = 'banana'` give you what you want? Or did you want the Max for Apple, and the Max for Orange and the Max for Banana?

Comment: I just want to get the last fruit purchased, based on the date regardless of which of the three fruits was purchased. so basically, if there were 10 entries for fruit purchases, and the last one was bought today, that would be the one that I want to show in the query - for example it should show 12.02.2016 Banana

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT top 1 DateOfPurchase, 
TypeOfFruit,
Quantity
FROM FruitInventory
WHERE TypeOfFruit = 'apple' OR
TypeOfFruit = 'orange' OR 
TypeOfFruit = 'banana'
order by DateOfPurchase desc
```